Whittaker function and gamma function
I am not an expert in special function. I would like to know if one of the following expressions can be simplify in some way, maybe using some other special functions (I tried with Coulomb wave functions but I did not succeed):
$$ (1) \hspace{1 cm} \Gamma\left(\mu - \kappa + \frac{1}{2} \right) W_{\kappa, \mu}(z)$$
$$ (2) \hspace{3  cm} \Gamma(a) \;  U(a, b, z)$$
where U is the Tricomi function, W is the Whittaker function and $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function. In my formula, $\mu$ in (1) can be an integer or a half integer and $\kappa$ is a general complex number. Thanks to everyone who will be able to help me.
Edit: I am reading something on the G-Meijer functions in those days. Do you know if there exists a way to express the formula (2) as single function of this kind?

In general expressing a confluent hypergeometric function in terms of Tricomi's or Whittaker's is the final result.  In particular specifying one parameter in Whittaker's function does not provide enough information to suggest a guess. Often it is found that there are few reductions.

Okay, so you say it is better to give up. I was completely lost in all the Erdeliy's tables. I hoped to find some better forms. Thank you anyway for your answer

I would not say " give up"; not every formula is known. In terms of this question more information would be needed (say the full series) to have the community be helpful. It terms named special functions (Gauss' hypergeometric, Whittaker, Laguerre, Hermite, etc) these are almost " fundamental " functions. Meaning expressions are stated in terms of these function and left as is. Example: Coulomb wave functions can be expressed in terms of Laguerre polynomials of Whittaker functions (Laguerre can be express in terms of Whittaker).
